# Symfony2 Error Using doctrine:generate:entities to Create Getters and Setters

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've created several entities in my first bundle without any problems. But when I create a new bundle, using the normal command:

```
php app/console generate:bundle
```

This creates a bundle structure with template files and registers the bundle in the app/config/AppKernel.php

I then created entities inside the new bundle folder: `/Acme/Bundle/Entity/`.

But when I go to generate the getters and setters with the command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBundle
```

It gives an error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                     
Bundle "AcmeBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

Why are these entities not being found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the fact that the new bundle is not automatically registered in the /app/config/config.yml file. So doctrine didn't know where to look for the entities evidently.

Maybe this isn't a problem if you only have one ORM database connection. But if you have defined multiple connections with special ORM mapping, you need to remember to register Every Single Bundle with the right entity manager connection:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: cms
        entity_managers:
            cms:
                connection: cms
                mappings:
                    GutensiteCmsBundle: ~
                    GutensiteArticleBundle: ~
            billing:
                connection: billing
                mappings:
                    GutensiteBillingBundle: ~
```

It seems like there should be a better way to have all entities use the default one by... "default" so you don't have to do this every time. Anyone know?

Comment: This got me again recently. I'm glad I answered this myself :D but I'd love to know if anyone else has a better automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss bundle name. You should create bundle like this `AcmeHelloBundle` and not `AcmeBundle` where `Hello` is a name of your bundle. Like this:

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle
```

Then run

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Acme
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. My example was just using generic names, where "Bundle" represented the name of the bundle, e.g. /Acme/Bundle is the same as Acme/HelloBundle. Sorry for the confusion. The answer I posted below turned out to be the solution, i.e. you have to register every single bundle with the ORM apparently.